# How to ignore source object in Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

This my  Source class

```
public class Content :IAggregateRoot
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string HeaderImage { get; set; }
        public string AboutText { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public long Phone { get; set; }
        public long Mobile { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }
    }
```

and this is my Destination class

```
public class AboutViewModel
    {
        public string AboutText { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public long Phone { get; set; }
        public long Mobile { get; set; }
    }
```

I just want to ignore extra properties of source and map source to destination with Automapper with this method

```
public static AboutViewModel ConvertToAboutViewModel(this Content content)
        {
           // Mapper.CreateMap<Content,AboutViewModel>().ForMember(x=>x.AboutText,)
            return Mapper.Map<Content, AboutViewModel>(content);
        }
```

How can I do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automapper would ignore those properties by default as they do not exist in the destination class.

Have you actually tried to run your code? if it is not working could you please post details of the error or exception you are getting.

You also need to define your basic map like this:

```
 Mapper.CreateMap<Content, AboutViewModel>();
 Mapper.CreateMap<AboutViewModel, Content>();
```

Ensure that the above code is ran before you call ConvertToAboutViewModel

Comment: yes, I would be glad if it did!Exception of type 'AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException' was thrown.

Comment: check my revision above, the Mapping needs to be setup, make sure the above code is ran before you attempt to call Mapper.Map